# Time and position in Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

If there are two different (ie: relative speed is not $0$) references frame, is it possible for $x$ and $x'$, or $t$ and $t'$ to be equal? It's not mathematically wrong.

Comment: yes, just use the Lorentz transformations, for instance, x=x' when $x=[\gamma v/(1-\gamma) ]t$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, in a stationary system, $x=5$ and there is another coordinate system moving at constant velocity parallel along its x axis, then there is nothing contradictory about that moving coordinate $x'=5$ aligning momentarily with $x=5$.

Similarly, two clocks can read the same time at a given moment even if their rates are different.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The reason why I posted this question is because I had a homework problem that asked me to prove t is not equal to t'. But I can't show that t=t' is mathematically wrong, so I kinda get confused.

Comment: Is it $t$ and not $dt$ or $\Delta t$? I would just  prove time dilation. there are a lot of proofs.  they probably meant $\Delta t$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation

Comment: yeah I guess the problem is asking for Δ, because proving t is not equal to t' does not make any sense.